# This website does not support workflows created by SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

Using SharePoint 2007 and Designer 2007, I'm trying to edit existing workflows. I know they exist on my list but I don't see them when browsing using SharePoint Designer. When I try to create a new one I get the error "This website does not support workflows created by SharePoint Designer".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This web site does not support workflows created by SharePoint Designer
Cause

```
Office SharePoint Designer 2007 is unable to detect that the server for your site is running either Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 or Windows SharePoint Services 3.0.
You do not have the permissions necessary to create workflows.
```

Resolution

```
Exit and then start Office SharePoint Designer 2007. If you are still unable to create workflows, it is possible either that the server is unavailable, or that the server is not running Office SharePoint Server 2007 or Windows SharePoint Services 3.0. Contact your server administrator for assistance.
The site owner should verify that the affected user has been added to the list of users who have permissions to the Workflows library. If not, add the user to the list:
    In Office SharePoint Designer 2007, in the Folder List, right-click the Workflows library, and then click Properties.
    Click the Security tab.
    Click Manage permissions using the browser.
    In the browser, on the Permissions: Workflows page, click New, and then click Add Users.
    Add the user to the list.
```

source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/troubleshoot-workflow-errors-HA010237912.aspx#BM18